# I have added products to the guest cart programmatically & I want the cart page to open with the cart products on clicking the cart url

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-community

**Output**

```
{
"response_code": "success",
"response_message": "unique cart url created successfully",
"response_data": {
    "cart_url": "http://local.trace.com/checkout/cart/"
}
```

}

If i click on above cart url, it should take me to cart page with cart products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs customization on masked id of quote. See table "quote_id_mask" saved mask id for each cart and you should use that mask id to initiate cart in magento.

So to achieve this. You need to create custom (controller) url with encrypted(for security purpose) cart id. In Custom Controller you need to set current quote to quote id you send in url.

hope this approach help.!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, i will try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do? A shared shopping cart where several users can add products? I once did something like this.

Generally speaking, it is when you add a product to the cart that a row is created in the quote table. You should, when creating a new quote, add an identifier (hash), which you will use later in the URL.
When you go to a given URL, you retrieve the hash and then retrieve the corresponding quote.

Comment: I want when user click on below url 
"http://local.trace.com/trace/cart/01HB14N3ALWu7vCpcn5raPTqxbQf010T"

he/she redirect to my custom controller then i retrive url hash code in my controller, but i dont know how its work